# How to calculate a database field with using other fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this crypto-application that needs to calculate the current market value of inserted values.

I have DB-Table called Crypto-Items.

Each crypto-item has three fields `"Crypto_Currency"`, `"Amount"` and `"Current market value"`

Crypto_currency can be any currency *"Bitcoin, Ripple, etc".*

The user can insert the Currency and Amount.

Now, when My user inserts their "Currency" and "Amount" and upon pressing create, I would need to do a calculation, I use a Bitfinex API to send the Selected currency to the api and then calculate the return with the amount inserted.

**My questions are**, where should this calculation be made? How would I access the data being sent such as "Crypto_Currency" or "amount"? How do I set them into the database.

The database in use is PostgreSQL.

My app is fully api based so this is the code to how a Crypto-item is made :

```
  # POST /crypto_items
  def create
    @crypto_item = CryptoItem.new(crypto_item_params)

    if @crypto_item.save
      render json: @crypto_item, status: :ok
    else
      render json: @crypto_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a hook?

You can create a `before_save` in the CryptoItem, something like this:

```rb
class CryptoItem < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :do_whatever

  private

  def do_whatever
    # Your calculation goes here.
    # you can assign the result of the Bitfinex API call 
    # to an attribute using self.attribute = ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Would this be written in the same controller where the POST request is or where should i make this?

Comment: How would I access any of the database fields or params, so if i wanted to do an if statement on a field called "crypto_currency" how would i go by doing that

Comment: I am assuming here that CryptoItem inherits from ApplicationRecord, so it has direct access to its columns in the database. The code I suggested would be, thus, inside a model named `cryto_item.rb`.

If there is a column named `crypto_currency` inside the crypto_items table, for example, you can simply call `crypto_currency` or `self.crypto_currency` from any method inside CryptoItem. It will do the trick.

Comment: Another thing: when you make `CryptoItem.new(crypto_item_params)` in the controller, if `crypto_item_params` is a hash containing key-value pairs with the columns in the database, the model CryptoItem will know how to build itself. For example, you said there is a column named `crypto_currency`. If you make `item = CryptoItem.new(crypto_currency: 'bitcoin')`, a later call to item.crypto_currency will return 'bitcoin'. On you do `item.save`, this value will be saved in the database.